# How would you generate this transaction hash?

Tags: web3js, ethereumjs, react

```
  let contract = await instance.mint(
          accounts,
          usersInput.url,
          usersInput.metadata[0],
          usersInput.metadata[1],
          usersInput.metadata[2],

          { from: accounts, gas: 350000 }
        );
        return contract;
```

If the user has low gas price, then the transaction will error with a message "TxHASH has timed out after 280 seconds"

Using truffle with has the latest web3 I assume.

How would I generate the transaction hash, or return the transaction hash and also send the transaction, so I can store the txHash and then scan for that receipt info when it takes longer than 280 seconds to confirm?

How do I return a tx hash in the code above, without waiting for actually being picked up. I'm confused on the syntax for the input to my function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would do:

```
let txHash = await instance.mint.sendTransaction(
    accounts,
    usersInput.url,
    usersInput.metadata[0],
    usersInput.metadata[1],
    usersInput.metadata[2],
    { from: accounts, gas: 350000 }
);
```

I am not sure this is documented anywhere :)

---

To wait for the receipt, you can use [my Gist](https://gist.github.com/xavierlepretre/88682e871f4ad07be4534ae560692ee6):

```
module.exports = function getTransactionReceiptMined(txHash, interval) {
    const self = this;
    const transactionReceiptAsync = function(resolve, reject) {
        self.getTransactionReceipt(txHash, (error, receipt) => {
            if (error) {
                reject(error);
            } else if (receipt == null) {
                setTimeout(
                    () => transactionReceiptAsync(resolve, reject),
                    interval ? interval : 500);
            } else {
                resolve(receipt);
            }
        });
    };

    if (Array.isArray(txHash)) {
        return Promise.all(txHash.map(
            oneTxHash => self.getTransactionReceiptMined(oneTxHash, interval)));
    } else if (typeof txHash === "string") {
        return new Promise(transactionReceiptAsync);
    } else {
        throw new Error("Invalid Type: " + txHash);
    }
};
```

Comment: This doesn't work. Ill post an edit in a bit why let me play with it thank you

Comment: If `mint` is undefined, then your problem is how you create `instance`. How do you created `instance`?

Comment: My instance is via truffle contract. And it was a typo, mint works now. Awesome it returns the txhash! Thanks!